# TextBox TextChange event is not working in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using asp textbox control with TextChange event, trying to set the text to label as the textbox text get changed but it is working when i loose the focus from textbox not when text changes.
the problem with loosing focus is that if i use AutoPostBack="true" it refresh the page which affects my other values...

my source for textbox on aspx page

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchCust" runat="server"  Width = "200" OnTextChanged="txtSearchCust_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

my code behind page source

```
 Protected Sub txtSearchCust_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearchCust.TextChanged
    QtyChk.Text=txtSearchCust.Text
 End Sub
```

here QtyChk is the label where I am trying to set the text
any solution...?

Comment: Probably, in this context, a solution based on Javascript should be more efficient

Comment: store value in session after postback to reassign value

Comment: have u read the question properly..!!!???

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doTextBoxChange() {
        __doPostBack();
    }
</script>
```

---

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onkeydown="return doTextBoxChange();"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

---

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If IsPostBack() Then
        LabelChange()
    End If
End Sub

Sub LabelChange()
    Label1.Text = "1234"
End Sub
```

But I think use javascript is a better option.

---

The values will disappear after post, you need to request the value and setup.
otherwise, use viewstate or session.

Using the javascript, don't post form data.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeyup="return doTextBoxChange();"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

```
 function doTextBoxChange() {
        var inputValue = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
        document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = inputValue;
 }
```

Comment: this is fine but using AutoPostBack="True" refreshes the page which affect my other values...